# Литература для создания серверной части игр

Tags: разработка-игр, java, gameserver, книги

Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы, товарищи, посоветовать книжки для создания серверной части игры. Желательно на русском. Игра не пошаговая, в реальном времени.

Comment: Исходный код Minecraft за литературу сойдет?

Comment: Именно этот код мне и нужно исправить. Брать код, который уже сам по себе, плохой, не есть хорошо.

Comment: Подскажите хотя бы в каком жанре планируется проект, может что-то и найдем. Просто реализация стратегий очень сильно отличается от шутеров к примеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что у вас сразу получится лучше, если вы просите посоветовать книжки ).

Но посмотрите, например, это:

- [Developing Games in Java](http://www.amazon.com/Developing-Games-Java-David-Brackeen/dp/1592730051/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327527622&sr=8-1)
- [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://www.amazon.com/Killer-Game-Programming-Andrew-Davison/dp/0596007302/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b)

Comment: Я дерзок, но даже я вижу что тот кто писал Minecraft, плохой программист.

Comment: Но ему уже неважно, он свои миллионы отхватил )